# Где найти хороший код?

Tags: c++, css

Хочу научиться читать чужой код. многие советуют начинать с хорошего кода.
во первых это легче, во вторых можно почерпнуть для себя много нового-как писать хороший код.

я столкнулся с такой проблемой-трудно найти хороший код.

во первых хороший код теряется в множестве плохих, а во вторых мне-начинающему программисту  сложно отличить действительно хороший код от не пойми чего.

где можно найти действительно хороший код??

Comment: Эммм, [GitHub](HTTP://github.com)

Comment: Слышал, Chromium очень хорошо написан.

Comment: @Niki-Timofe Если вам несложно, то ткните носом в хорошие `C++` проекты на `GitHub'e`. А то я кроме `folly` ничего не видел.

Comment: Зачем читать хороший код, лучше пишите свой.

Comment: @igumnov, 

    Зачем читать хороший код, лучше пишите свой

это из серии  "чукча не читатель, чукча - писатель" ?

Comment: могу посоветовать, какой код не должен быть))))
http://govnokod.ru/

Comment: В качестве ответа на вопрос "где найти хороший код?" рекомендовать opensource-помойку ***hub.com -- весьма показательный симптом современного гниения программирования, особенно в рашке.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- Если речь идет только `C++,` то я бы лично смотрел в сторону гугловских `opensource` проектов, поскольку такой код однозначно требует таланта:

> - **[Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/index?hl=ru)**
> - **[Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/)**
> - **[gperftools](http://code.google.com/p/gperftools/)**
> - **[googletest](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/)**
> - **[google-glog](http://code.google.com/p/google-glog)**

- Также крайне рекомендую читать код [**Qt.**](http://qt.gitorious.org/)

Comment: Кстати, а как насчет исходников Boost?

Comment: @mikillskegg

- Я в последнее время немного охладел к темплейтам. Понятно, что, читая `boost,` можно узнать тонну всего интересного и полезного, но протаскивать такие привычки в `production` не стоит.

- Как я себе сейчас представляю, задача `boost'a` заключается в том, чтобы демонстрировать `bleeding edge` возможностей шаблонного программирования, взрывать умы новичкам и потихоньку переползать в `Standard Library.`

Comment: Все хорошо в меру и к месту. Бывают случаи, когда темплейты помогают писать быстро и эффективно. Но знать их и знать хорошо - нужно.

И потом, не все библиотеки в бусте заверчены исключительно на темплейтах. Есть и более приземленные варианты.

Comment: @Котик\_хочет\_кушать, я полазил в [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/index?hl=ru), куча хорошей документации, примеры использования, но сам код классов в .h что-то найти не смог.

Он там вообще-то есть?

-- update --

а вот в [Chromium](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/) нашел.

Comment: @avp

- [`Protobuf` на `code.google.com`](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/source/browse/)

- `Chromium,` кстати, удобнее читать [здесь](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/source/browse/) (если не `clon'`ить репозиторий себе на машину).

Answer (score 4):

Советую почитать дядюшку Боба "[Чистый код. Создание, анализ и рефакторинг](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5011068/)". Ну или хотябы 17 главу "Запахи и эвристические правила", чтобы отличать хороший код от индусского (:

Comment: да, как раз собирался её прочитать, спасибо:)

Answer (score 0):

я пишу свои коды в msvs, по ходу написания своего кода возникают вопросы использование например "внешних" функций от сторонних разработчиков, приходится заглядывать в код заголовочных файлов написанных не мной и разбирать как там все реализовано, а в них как раз все правильно реализовано и оформлено. так вот и учусь на чужих кодах + интернет